# Merging an array property with the same key within an object

Tags: javascript

If I want to append to an existing property that's an array, what's the cleanest solution?

```
function adminConditional(user) {
    return {
      ...user,
      priority: 1,
      access: ['system2']
  }
}

console.log(
  {
    ...(adminConditional)({name: "andrew", type: "Admin"}), // function name can vary
    access: ['system1'] // always set
  }
)

// Expected output:
{
  access: ["system1", "system2"],
  name: "andrew",
  priority: 1,
  type: "Admin"
}
// Actual output:
{
  access: ["system1"],
  name: "andrew",
  priority: 1,
  type: "Admin"
}
```

It instead overwrites the index of `access` with the last assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify logic

```js
function adminConditional(user) {
  return {
    ...user,
    priority: 1,
    access: ['system2', ...user.access]
  };
}

console.log(
  {
    ...(adminConditional)({
      name: "andrew",
      type: "Admin",
      access: ['system1']
    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

To append to an array using spread syntax you can use the syntax:

```
let arr = [1,2,3];
let newArr = [...arr, 4];
```

newArr will contain `[1,2,3,4]`.
The same can be applied within an object, just reference the property using the spread operator into the function and you can achieve the same result:

```
function adminConditional(user) {
    return {
      ...user,
      priority: 1,
      access: ['system2']
  }
}

console.log(
  {
    ...(adminConditional)({name: "andrew", type: "Admin"}),
    access: [...(adminConditional)({name: "andrew", type: "Admin"}).access, 'system1']
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to avoid duplicates in `access`, and avoid calling the function twice, so then there is no short way to do this. I would suggest:

```js
function adminConditional(user) {
    return {
      ...user,
      priority: 1,
      access: ['system2']
  }
}

let user = adminConditional({name: "andrew", type: "Admin"});
console.log(
  {
    ...user,
    access: [...new Set(['system1', ...user.access])]
  }
)
```